# Why is the source package name of Kernel image changed from 'linux' to 'linux-signed' in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

First, some background, if you try to type:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package} -- ${Source}\n' | grep linux
```

in `Ubuntu 18.04`, you find those binary packages and their corresponding source packages.
among them, you can find the following correspondence:

```
binary package                   source package
-----------------------------------------------     
linux-image-4.15.0-xx-generic    linux-signed       
linux-image-generic              linux-meta         
linux-generic                    linux-meta
linux-headers-4.15.0-xx          linux
```

Question:
the binary package `linux-image-X.X.X-generic` used to have source package named `linux` until recently, as shown above, to have been changed to `linux-signed`, what is the difference and implication of such a change?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the advantage of a signed kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264100/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-signed-kernel)

Comment: @CaldeiraG one difference is that I didn't specify to install a signed kernel. neither does the package name showing it's a signed kernel ( apart from the source package name ).